# remove_action hook not working to remove credit card fields from donation form GiveWP

Tags: wordpress

I have used below action hook to hide fields but it is not working.

```
remove_action( 'give_cc_form', 'give_get_cc_form' );
```

can anyone help me to figure out this issue

I am using GiveWP plugin for donation in WordPress site.

Comment: You need to set possible heigest priority as compared to plugin add action.

Answer (score 0):

GiveWP has a pretty expansive snippet library, and one example shows how you can remove and rearrange fields. This is probably the best place to start from:
https://github.com/impress-org/givewp-snippet-library/blob/master/form-customizations/customize-fieldset-order.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function give_remove_fieldsets() {

    remove_action( 'give_cc_form', 'give_get_cc_form' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'give_remove_fieldsets' );
```

this actually worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to run it at init, and you need to add the same priority used in the add_action, if none it uses 10 and the priority can be left blank

```
add_action('init','remove_actions');
function remove_actions() {
  remove_action( 'give_cc_form', 'give_get_cc_form', 1 ); // Replace the priority with the correct one
}
```

Comment: I am using add_action( 'give_donation_form_after_cc_form) for this

Comment: does the add_action have a 3rd parameter ? (this indicates the priority) if this is not set you can use 10 or leave it blank in the remove action, and make sure you call the remove_action on the correct hook. in your question you use `give_cc_form` but in the comment to the awnser you say its added using `give_donation_form_after_cc_form`

Comment: yes, you are right. i have added priority as 10 and used same function hook give_donation_form_after_cc_form